# Send a packet from 32 bit and Receive in 64 bit machine

Tags: c, linux, sockets, 32bit-64bit

I'm writing a program that exchanges messages between different bit machines. My Send, Receive and readn functions look like below. Problem is I have a packet format in which I send messages. Packet type determines what type of message like Welcome, Data, Username etc. I read the packet type from the sd and then read the remaining data. When I send from 32 bit, packet type will be x to x+4 and and data will be x+4 to so on. While receiving, on 64 bit machine, packet type is read from x to x+8 and x+8 as data and so my read function waits forever to get the remaining bytes of length as specified. How do I fix this problem in this code ?

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* messsges received/sent by server */
#define WELCOME_MSG    0
#define USER_NAME     1
#define EMAIL_MSG_TO_SERVER    2
#define EMAIL_MSG_TO_CLIENT 3
#define CLOSE_CON 4
/* structure of a packet */
typedef struct _packet {

    /* packet type */
    char      type;

    /* packet length */
    long      lent;

    /* packet text */
    char *    text;

} Packet;

int readn(int sd, char *buf, size_t n) {
    printf("readn via utils. %d, %s, %d\n", sd, buf, n);
    size_t toberead = n;
    char * ptr = buf;

    while (toberead > 0) {

        int errno_save = 0;

        fprintf(stderr, "toberead: %zu\n", toberead);

        ssize_t  byteread = read(sd, ptr, toberead);
        errno_save = errno;

        fprintf(stderr, "toberead: %zu, byteread: %zd\n", toberead, byteread);

        if (byteread <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "byteread val: %d",byteread);
            if (byteread == -1)
            {
                perror("read");
                errno = errno_save;
            }
            return (0);
        }

        toberead -= byteread;
        ptr += byteread;
    }

    if ('\0' != buf[n]) /* This assumes buf is one byte **larger** then n. */
    {
        buf[n] = '\0';
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Finished readn. %s\n", buf);
    return (1);
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------*/



Packet *recvpkt(int sd)
{
    printf("Recvpkt via utils.\n");
    Packet *pkt;

    /* allocate space for the pkt */
    pkt = (Packet *) calloc(1, sizeof(Packet));
    if (!pkt) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error : unable to calloc\n");
        return(NULL);
    }

    /* read the message type */
    if (!readn(sd, (char *) &pkt->type, sizeof(pkt->type))) {
        free(pkt);
        return(NULL);
    }

    /* read the message length */
    if (!readn(sd, (char *) &pkt->lent, sizeof(pkt->lent))) {
        free(pkt);
        return(NULL);
    }
    pkt->lent = ntohl(pkt->lent);

    /* allocate space for message text */
    if (pkt->lent > 0) {
        pkt->text = (char *) malloc(pkt->lent);
        if (!pkt) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error : unable to malloc\n");
            return(NULL);
        }

        /* read the message text */
        if (!readn(sd, pkt->text, pkt->lent)) {
            freepkt(pkt);
            return(NULL);
        }
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Reading packet complete succesfully.\n");

    /* done reading */
    return(pkt);
}

int sendpkt(int sd, char typ, long len, char *buf)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Send packet via utils. sd: %d, typ: %c, len: %lu, buf: %s\n", sd, typ, len, buf);
    char tmp[8];
    long siz;

    /* write type and lent */
    bcopy(&typ, tmp, sizeof(typ));
    siz = htonl(len);
    bcopy((char *) &siz, tmp+sizeof(typ), sizeof(len));
    write(sd, tmp, sizeof(typ) + sizeof(len));

    /* write message text */
    if (len > 0)
        write(sd, buf, len);
    return(1);
}

void freepkt(Packet *pkt)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Freeing packet.\n");
    free(pkt->text);
    free(pkt);
}
```

Comment: Never use `int` or `long` in packets or similar data. That's what `uint32_t` and friends are for.

Comment: Don't use `structs` as network protocols at all. You've just discovered one reason why, and there are about five others. Design yourself a wire protocol, defined in octets, and write the code to send and receive it.

Comment: Like EJP says, basically..

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using structs for network protocols, you just have to make sure they use the same data alignment on both ends, using direct `#pragma` statements or cross-platform `pshpack...` header files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `stdint.h` header, which defines types with names that tell you their size.  They will always be that size on any platform.

```
#include <stdint.h>

/* structure of a packet */
typedef struct _packet {
    /* packet type */
    uint8_t  type;
    /* packet length */
    uint32_t lent;
    /* packet text */
    char *   text;
} Packet;
```

Comment: Data types are only half the problem. Data alignment is the other half. If you send structs over sockets, you have to not only use the same data types, but also the same struct alignment as well. Unless you send each struct member individually, then alignment does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to agree a common binary format that all parties adhere to. I suspect that you are aware of that but do not realise that some types have different sizes on different machines. You likely are working with machines for which long has different sizes. And you declared your length data to have type long. So on some machines it is 32 bits, and on others it is 64 bits.

You should probably decide to use a 32 bit integer. You need to use a type whose size does not vary on different machines. For instance int32_t.

Comment: I was aware of int32_t etc but never realized their importance after doing bug fixing for 3 years in C++. I did not care to understand that earlier until I wrote code myself. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I was able to immediately realize the solution after seeing the code, but your explanation gave me more knowledge.